# Can't load a specific page on codeigniter "slug"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to load a specific page within a controller. I followed the Codeigniter tutorial and the main pages work but the individual page (loaded with view) doesn't load according to the given slug.

**blog.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/index
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/Index/index
 *  - or -

 */

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('blog_model');
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
} 
public function index()
{
    $data['post'] = $this->blog_model->get_posts();
    $data['title'] = 'Blog archive';

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('blog', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}

public function view($slug = NULL)
{
    $data['post'] = $this->blog_model->get_posts($slug);    

     if (empty($data['post']))
    {
            show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('post', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
}
```

**blog_model.php**

```
<?php
class Blog_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_posts($slug = FALSE)
    {

    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('blog_posts');
            $this->db->join('category', 'category.id = blog_posts.category_id');
            $this->db->join('author', 'author.id = blog_posts.author_id');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
    }

    $this->db->select('*');
    // $this->db->from('blog_posts');
    $this->db->join('category', 'category.id = blog_posts.category_id');
    $this->db->join('author', 'author.id = blog_posts.author_id');
    // $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    $query = $this->db->get_where('blog_posts', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
    }

}
```

As you can see I tried a few combinations because I'm not sure it's retrieving the table in get_posts when slug is not false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

call `url_helper` helper in `__construct` like following

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Now, update the routes.php like following

If your URL like

> http://www.example.com/blog/view/slug

Your ruote should be like this

```
$route['blog/view/(:any)'] = 'blog/view/$1';
```

If your URL like

> http://www.example.com/view/slug

Your ruote should be like this

```
$route['view/(:any)'] = 'blog/view/$1';
```

And, your `get_posts` model function repeating queries, use it simply like below

```
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('blog_posts');
    $this->db->join('category', 'category.id = blog_posts.category_id');
    $this->db->join('author', 'author.id = blog_posts.author_id');
    if($slug){
        $this->db->where(compact('slug'));
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() > 1) ? $query->result_array() : $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it by modifying the routes:

At first I had:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['blog'] = 'blog';
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/$1';
```

So I changed it to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['blog'] = 'blog';
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/view/$1';
```

And changed the method name in blog.php from blog to view. "view" looks more standard than "blog" so I left it that way. In 'blog/view/$1' represents the controller, view the method and of course $1 is the first param. Actually if I try Blog/view/hello-world it works too.

Comment: What should I write there? Or should I just leave it blank? Right now it works just fine.